# How to create Charts in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I tried creating a Chart in Xamarin.Forms but I wasn't able to show it. I also want to know where am I gonna put this code. Is it in .xaml or in .xaml.cs? 
I'm just a beginner in using Xamarin so maybe someone can help me.

This is the code that I to use.

```
using BarChart;
...

protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
  base.OnCreate (bundle);

  var data = new [] { 1f, 2f, 4f, 8f, 16f, 32f };
  var chart = new BarChartView (this) {
    ItemsSource = Array.ConvertAll (data, v => new BarModel { Value = v })
  };

  AddContentView (chart, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent));
}
```

Comment: Which chart library are you trying to use ?

Comment: Actually Sir, I don't know. This is my first try creating a Chart. I just copied the code on the Internet hoping it will run. What do I need to do?

Comment: @Kowalski Most likely this one: [Bar Chart](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/barchart). Which isn't for Xamarin Forms.

Comment: @Nfear What chart can I use instead?

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista have a look at OxyPlot, which is free. A paid alternative would be Syncfusion.

Comment: I've heard about that many times now. How can I download that? Is that kind of a library or something?

Answer (score 5):

There isn't really any Charting Control that comes with Xamarin.Forms. Syncfusion which offers [great Charting Controls](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin/chart) for Xamarin.Forms come with a [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) which offers them for free.

[Here is a full example by Xamarin using SyncFusion Chart Controls](https://blog.xamarin.com/visualize-your-data-with-charts-graphs-and-xamarin-forms/)

Answer (score 4):

I presume this code is in your mainactivty right now, but when working with Xamarin Forms the UI portion is not create there. It is created in the Shared code.

If you really want to use Xamarin forms I would recommend the following steps:

First follow this to get started with and understanding how to use Xamarin Forms : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/

And then Oxyplot (this is a charting libary for Xamarin Forms): https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/OxyPlotDemo

Comment: @Sanne Where should I put the Sample Code about Oxyplot? Should I put it in .xaml or .xaml.cs?

Comment: If you use xaml you should put UI code in the XAML en and the C# code in the CS file. If you want to do everything in code and nothing in XAML than you should create class that inhert from contentpage

Comment: The thing is, I want my codes to be in .XAML but some codes on the internet on how to create UI elements (e.g: Searchbar, Picker, etc) is written on a C# code. Is there a way I can code those kind of things on a .XAML format?

Comment: Please read the gettting started url i pasted in to get a better understanding on the XAML and how to make your UI in it

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin charts provided by SciChart can be used in Xamarin Forms.

Check out the [Xamarin Chart examples here](https://www.scichart.com/examples/xamarin-chart/):

[image]

While [SciChart](https://www.scichart.com) is a native Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android chart control, it can be used in [Xamarin Forms as per this FAQ](https://blog.xamarin.com/embedding-native-controls-into-xamarin-forms/).

*Disclosure: I am the tech lead on the Xamarin Charts project*